# JVM & Glassfish 32 bit vs 64 bit

Tags: java, jvm, glassfish, 32bit-64bit

I'm setting up production server Windows 2008 64bit with 8gb ram and 4core xeon cpu. It will have some oracle services and Glassfish. I wonder if it's worth to install 64 bit jvm or stay with 32 bit?
We will run e-commerce application and preapre for 100 users/day. We also use jpa caching.
Would 64bit jvm be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HotSpot FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_performance) seems to imply that it would be slower if anything:

> The performance difference comparing an application running on a 64-bit platform versus a 32-bit platform on SPARC is on the order of 10-20% degradation when you move to a 64-bit VM.  On AMD64 and EM64T platforms this difference ranges from 0-15% depending on the amount of pointer accessing your application performs.

Answer (score 0):

If your want to go with 32-bit then it makes sense especially if your plan is to setup 4 or 5 32-bit Glassfish servers as a cluster on the same system, each with a max of 1.25GB of RAM or so.   Otherwise,  you could run one 64-bit Glassfish server and it would theoretically be able to use up all 8GB of ram if your code needed it.

So, you could start with one Glassfish JVM, and as users come online, increasing load, you could add addtional JVMs to [your cluster](http://dsc.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/glassfishcluster/)  and also a NGINX/Tomcat  server to load balance.